# How to change the current axis instance (i.e., gca()) in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, subplot

I use a trick to [draw a colorbar whose height matches the master axes](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#colorbar-whose-height-or-width-in-sync-with-the-master-axes). The code is like

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np

ax = plt.subplot(111)
im = ax.imshow(np.arange(100).reshape((10,10)))

# create an axes on the right side of ax. The width of cax will be 5%
# of ax and the padding between cax and ax will be fixed at 0.05 inch.
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)

plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
```

This trick works good. However, since a new axis is appended, the current instance of the figure becomes cax - the appended axis. As a result, if one performs operations like

```py
plt.text(0,0,'whatever')
```

the text will be drawn on `cax` instead of `ax` - the axis to which `im` belongs.

Meanwhile, `gcf().axes` shows both axes.

My question is: How to make the current axis instance (returned by `gca()`) the original axis to which `im` belongs.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Use [`plt.sca(ax)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.sca) to set the current axes, where `ax` is the `Axes` object you'd like to become active.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the current Axes instance, it's possible to simply index the desired Axes instance the list of Axes in the Figure (as OP mentioned):

```py
plt.gcf().axes[0].text(0, 0, 'whatever')
```

or in the specific example, since the subplot is already assigned to a variable name, simply use it as is.

```py
ax.text(0, 0, 'whatever')
```