# plot an input point on a image with pyplot

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, input

I want to plot an image with pyplot and on top of that image a point.
That point is from an input field in the pyplot. Here I have a piece of code, where you can put a point in, but after pressing enter, or search button it won't plot the point. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox

def imshow_rgb(img_bgr):
    img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    plt.imshow(img_rgb)

ims = cv2.imread('plattegrondtekening.png', 1)
fig = plt.imshow(np.flipud(ims), cmap='gray', origin='lower')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

initial_text = ""
x,y=[500,500]

def submit(text):
    x,y = list(map(int,text.split(",")))
    print(x,y)
    plt.plot(x, y, "ro")
    plt.show()
    
axbox = plt.axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.8, 0.075])
text_box = TextBox(axbox, 'search', initial=initial_text)
text_box.on_submit(submit)

plt.show()
```

[image plot with input field below, this is the output of the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ry6G.png)

But I want that it shows a point on x=900 and y=800, when I enter 900,800 in the input box.

Answer (score 0):

We have to select the active axes first using `plt.sca(ax)` and for refreshing the canvas we may use `fig.canvas.draw()` and `fig.canvas.flush_events()`.

- Replace `fig = plt.imshow(np.flipud(ims), cmap='gray', origin='lower')` with:

  ```
   fig = plt.figure()  # Keep the figure for later usage.
   ax = plt.gca()  # Keep the axes for later usage.
   ax.imshow(np.flipud(ims), cmap='gray', origin='lower')  # Show the image on axes ax
  ```
- Replace `plt.plot(x, y, "ro")` and `plt.show()` with:

  ```
   plt.sca(ax)  # Set active axes
   plt.plot(x, y, "ro")
   fig.canvas.draw()  # Refresh the canvas.
   fig.canvas.flush_events()
  ```

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox

ims = cv2.imread('plattegrondtekening.png', 1)
fig = plt.figure()  # Keep fig for later usage
ax = plt.gca()  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505341/how-to-get-the-axesimages-from-matplotlib
ax.imshow(np.flipud(ims), cmap='gray', origin='lower')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

initial_text = ""
x,y=[500,500]

def submit(text):
    x, y = list(map(int,text.split(",")))
    print(x,y)
    plt.sca(ax)  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625563/matplotlib-change-the-current-axis-instance-i-e-gca
    plt.plot(x, y, "ro")
    fig.canvas.draw()  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/how-to-update-a-plot-in-matplotlib
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    
axbox = plt.axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.8, 0.075])
text_box = TextBox(axbox, 'search', initial=initial_text)
text_box.on_submit(submit)
plt.show()
```